# Fading out linear gradient. CSS or image?

Tags: css, shadow, linear-gradients

I made this shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/PaFyt/ (webkit)

Just 6 fading out linear gradients set up with:

```
background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 1px, 0px 2px, 0px 3px, 0px 4px, 0px 5px;
```

And I wonder if this is a good way to make fading out shadows?

Or batter just use image? Image will have better compability...

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you use pure CSS since most modern browsers support it but always prepare image  equivalents as fallback for older browsers. The less image files, the faster the site!

[An article that may help from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).